# Real-time data from PHP background process

Tags: php, html, shell, background-process

I'm currently working on a project that uses the twitter firehose to grab tweets and process/do an action on an Arduino. The PHP that does all of this runs as a background process from terminal on my local machine. What I'd love to do is somehow grab the data real-time on some sort of front end page without having to reload it every time. So basically something like...

Guy tweets..
tweet is received and processed with PHP...
Somehow tweet is then grabbed by front end and appended to list live on screen.

Would the only solution be to run a continuous jquery ajax call to see if new data exists in a SQL database? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that on the client side. So, you can use ajax or websockets.